# Test driven development for react js

Tags: reactjs, tdd, integration-testing

Just started learning the React js.Some of testing libraries such as chai,Sinon,Enzyme and mocha is used for unit testing. Is there any testing library is available for test driven development practices in react js. One more question how to test the page navigation in react js since the state and props will be updated once the page is submitted. Note:Through react router it would navigate to other page. how to write the test cases for integration testing.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a specific testing library for Test Driven Development (TDD). It's just a methodology whereby you define your tests before coding the functionality.

Not sure what you are asking exactly in the second part of your question, but you might be after snapshot testing of your React components: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/snapshot-testing.html.

Comment: Thanks for the update.My questions is when the user clicks the submit button then it should navigate to next page.How to write the test cases for this in React js application.

Comment: You don't need to be writing tests for react router. They will have already covered this. Instead, I suspect you want to check that your component is behaving as expected, maybe calling a function which does a couple of things and then calls `this.props.history.push('/somepath')`. If you're using jest you could just do an assertion to check whether the function is called in the first place. Or you could mock the history object in the props and check whether it gets called? See: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html#tohavebeencalled